# Spring Boot application won't start from Eclipse, but works from Cygwin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-boot

I started to work on Spring Boot application from scratch and  I configure it as it is described on [[http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/]](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/%5d).

It was possible to run it from Cygwin and also from Eclipse.
But the problem occurred when I tried to add dependency to another project in my *gradle.build*.

I've added *compile(project(':my.another.project'))* to dependencies section in *gradle.build* and from that point it was not possible to run it from Eclipse. But from cygwin everything works normally.

I tried to change dependency to some other project but there is still the same error. When I remove all dependencies everything works fine.

So, basically from Cygwin everything works fine and it fails in Eclipse when project has dependencies to another projects.
 Do you have any idea where might me a problem?

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@389cce04: startup date [Fri Jun 13 11:42:55 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at eu.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:19)

2014-06-13 11:42:55.901  WARN 9408 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@389cce04: startup date [Fri Jun 13 11:42:55 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at eu.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:19)

2014-06-13 11:42:55.902  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4a0c85dc: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,application,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,helloController,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationSorter.<init>(AutoConfigurationSorter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:66)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:377)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at eu.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the Eclipse metadata when you added the extra project? You would need to tell Eclipse that your project depends on the extra one (e.g. using `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` if that's how you did it originally).

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately didn't help. There is the same error.

Comment: I guess you need to share your code and complete steps to reproduce then, since it doesn't look like anything run of the mill (works for everyone else).