# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor: method <init>()V not found

Tags: spring, nosuchmethoderror

I'm testing my first Spring project. I'm trying to call a webservice. I'm following the tutorial as listed here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/

When I try to build my project, I get following error:

```
2014-09-08 15:10:38.924  INFO 4736 --- [           main] b.i.einvoice.webserviceTest.TestMain     : Starting TestMain on W7-010545 with PID 4736 (C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice\target\classes started by staelko in C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice)
2014-09-08 15:10:38.978  INFO 4736 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@12d56b37: startup date [Mon Sep 08 15:10:38 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor: method <init>()V not found
```

What is causing this?

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.icredit</groupId>
    <artifactId>einvoice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>einvoice Portlet</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.10.6</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.version>6.2.1</liferay.version>
        <spring.suite.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.suite.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>

                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>BatchDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.BatchDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>BatchDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerAccountDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerAccountDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerAccountDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>CustomerDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>CustomerDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>DocumentTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.DocumentTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>DocumentTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailStatusDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailStatusDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailStatusDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>EmailTemplateDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.EmailTemplateDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>EmailTemplateDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>FileService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.FileService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>FileService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>SenderDaoService-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                            <generatePackage>be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.SenderDaoService</generatePackage>
                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                            <schemas>
                                <schema>
                                    <fileset>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaDirectory -->
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/</directory>
                                        <!-- Defaults to schemaIncludes -->
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>SenderDaoService.wsdl</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </fileset>
                                </schema>
                            </schemas>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.suite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Full stack trace below:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.1.6.RELEASE)

2014-09-08 15:26:06.200  INFO 2964 --- [           main] b.i.einvoice.webserviceTest.TestMain     : Starting TestMain on W7-010545 with PID 2964 (C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice\target\classes started by staelko in C:\Users\staelko\git\einvoice-portlets\einvoice)
2014-09-08 15:26:06.273  INFO 2964 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@326b9c84: startup date [Mon Sep 08 15:26:06 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAwareProcessor: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.WebApplicationContextServletContextAwareProcessor.<init>(WebApplicationContextServletContextAwareProcessor.java:40)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.postProcessBeanFactory(AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at be.icredit.einvoice.webserviceTest.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:13)
2014-09-08 15:26:06.307  INFO 2964 --- [       Thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@326b9c84: startup date [Mon Sep 08 15:26:06 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-09-08 15:26:06.319  WARN 2964 --- [       Thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@326b9c84: startup date [Mon Sep 08 15:26:06 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:980)

2014-09-08 15:26:06.320  WARN 2964 --- [       Thread-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@326b9c84: startup date [Mon Sep 08 15:26:06 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:980)

2014-09-08 15:26:06.321  INFO 2964 --- [       Thread-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@331c89c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,customerDaoConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
```

On this line in my main class crashes the app:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CustomerDaoConfiguration.class, args);
```

And my CustomerDaoConfiguration is listed as below:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomerDaoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("be.icredit.einvoice.proxy.CustomerDaoService");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerClient weatherClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        CustomerClient client = new CustomerClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://ws08-icreditlc.iconos.be:18080/icredit-service-data/CustomerDaoService");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

}
```

Comment: Weird, the ServletContextAwareProcessor class has a no-arg constructor so I don't see what would cause its initialization to fail in such way. Can you post full stack trace ?

Comment: Added full stacktrace in original post

Comment: I do use maven to build my project. I also use Eclipse. Is it wrong to test this by using Run as Java Application ?

Comment: Nope should be fine (except you won't run any **tests** that way unless you specifically chose one. Otherwise Eclipse will instruct the JVM to start from some entry point you may not even be aware of, especially when dealing with Spring Boot). Someone [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202921/spring-boot-application-wont-start-from-eclipse-but-works-from-cygwin) seems to have similar problem with Spring Boot (but he's using gradle instead of maven).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this problem because I included another spring framework with an older version. To check if you have the same problem, run the following command to generate a dependency tree:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Then search through the output to check if you have included another spring framework with an older version(typically 2.xx or 3.xx).

Answer (score 4):

Are you using an IDE? I had the exact same problem when I was using IntelliJ, but when I ran it from terminal by

```
 mvn  spring-boot:run
```

It would run fine. To make it work in IntelliJ I had to go to "project structure"->"Modules"-> "Dependencies" and move the resources around or by manually moving them in .iml file.

From Spring documentation:

`IntelliJ IDEA orders the classpath differently depending on how you run your application. Running your application in the IDE via its main method will result in a different ordering to when you run your application using Maven or Gradle or from its pacakaged jar. This can cause Spring Boot to fail to find the templates on the classpath. If you’re affected by this problem you can reorder the classpath in the IDE to place the module’s classes and resources first. Alternatively, you can configure the template prefix to search every templates directory on the classpath: classpath*:/templates/.`